# XDocReport : XDocConverterException: Cannot find converters from=DOCX

Tags: xdocreport

I'm testing the sample code from XDocReport. And I combined, creating a docx and pdf report based on a docx template. However I keep on getting this message

```
Apr 21, 2016 5:39:10 PM fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterRegistry internalFindConverter
SEVERE: Cannot find converters from=DOCX
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.XDocConverterException: Cannot find converters from=DOCX
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterRegistry.internalFindConverter(ConverterRegistry.java:121)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterRegistry.findConverter(ConverterRegistry.java:74)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.getConverter(AbstractXDocReport.java:667)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.convert(AbstractXDocReport.java:690)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.samples.docxandfreemarker.DocxProjectWithFreemarkerList.main(DocxProjectWithFreemarkerList.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Here's the code :

```
try
        {
            InputStream in = DocxProjectWithFreemarker.class.getResourceAsStream( "DocxProjectWithFreemarkerList.docx" );
            IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport( in, TemplateEngineKind.Freemarker );

            FieldsMetadata metadata = report.createFieldsMetadata();

            metadata.load( "developers", Developer.class, true );

            IContext context = report.createContext();
            Project project = new Project( "XDocReport" );
            context.put( "project", project );

            List<Developer> developers = new ArrayList<Developer>();
            developers.add( new Developer( "ZERR", "Angelo", "angelo.zerr@gmail.com" ) );
            developers.add( new Developer( "Leclercq", "Pascal", "pascal.leclercq@gmail.com" ) );

            context.put( "developers", developers );

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File( "DocxProjectWithFreemarkerList_Out.docx" ) );
            report.process( context, out );

//            ===========================================================================================

            Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF);

            OutputStream outt = new FileOutputStream(new File("DocxProjectWithFreemarkerList_Out.pdf"));
            report.convert(context, options, outt);

        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( XDocReportException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? How can I fix that error?

Comment: I don't know the product, but `Cannot find converters from=DOCX` seems to suggest that some module may be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the same than [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xdocreport/u2MQiR0dCFU).

You need to have **fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.xwpf** JARs and her dependencies JARs (iText, etc) in your classpath.